# Other than text how to remove numbers , punctuation, white spaces and special characters from text?

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I just scraped text data from a website and that data contains numbers, special characters and punctuation. After splitting the data and I tried to keep plain text but I'm getting spcaes, numbers, special characters. How to remove all those things and keep the text free from above things.

```
url = 'www.example.com'
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
text = get_text(html)
extracted_data = text.split()
refined_data = []
SYMBOLS = '{}()[].,:;+-*/&|<>=~0123456789'
for i in extracted_data:
    if i not in SYMBOLS:
       refined_data.append(i)
print("\n", "$" * 50, "HEYAAA we got arround: ", len(refined_data), " of keywords! Here are they: ","$" * 50, "\n")
print(type(refined_data)) 


output:

1.My
2.system
3.showing
4.error
5.404
6.I
7.don't
8.understand
9.why
10. it
11. showing ,
12.like
13.this?
14.53251
15.$45
```

Comment: As there are many cases for what you are asking, Its better to show sample text and desired output

Comment: @ashishmishra I just added an example output. The text which extracted contains more punctuations, white spaces, numbers and special characters. So I want to clear all those from my text and keep my text plain.

Answer (score 1):

`extracted_data` is the result of string.split()

The string.split() method used as such will split your text along 'any whitespaces'.

The `not in` operator compares `i` (**the entire string**) to a **sequence**. Your sequence here is just a single string, so it's like a list of the individual characters in that string.

So is 'system' in the sequence `SYMBOLS`? Asked again: is the string 'system' any of the characters in `SYMBOLS`? No it is not. Therefore, your if statement is executed and it is appended to your product.

Is '53251' in the list of one characters `SYMBOLS`? Not it is not. Therefore, it is appended.

And so on.

---

Such a list comparison is not necessary. You should be using [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: where should I use it exactly?